# Polling vs handshaking in hardware

Tags: hardware, polling, handshake, bus, peripherals

Brookshear & Brylow's *Computer Science: An Overview* (12th ed.) states the following:

> a process such as printing a document involves a constant two-way dialogue, known as **handshaking**, in which the computer and the peripheral device exchange information about the device’s status and coordinate their activities.

I'm more familiar with "handshaking" as the process of establishing a TCP connection, and "polling" as the technique of repeatedly checking the status of a hardware device.

This [ScienceDirect summary](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/hardware-handshaking) complicates things further, mentioning two kinds of handshaking - hardware and software - neither of which has the meaning I'm familiar with.

So  what is the exact relationship between "handshaking" and "polling"?

Answer (score 0):

Handshaking is a multistage process where devices establish a connection and confirm that they are listening/talking to each other. It is a way to ensure, to a certain degree, that data will go to the right place and it will be received.

Polling, as you said, is just repeatedly checking a status of the device. As for relationship, you need to have a way to get polling data and handshaking is often a way to establish this connection

Comment: But those two sources don't describe it as a means of establishing a connection, but as the check itself.